# Unable to access computers on VPN

Tags: vpn

Recently switched ISPs; ISP modem is in bridge mode connected to the WAN port on my Synology MR2200ac. All works well except I cannot see client computers on a VPN that starts with 192.168.x.x. My own IP is 192.168.4.x, so I don't see why there is a conflict. Some clients are 192.168.54.x, 192.168.1.x, 192.168.70.x. The only client I can VPN into and see machines is a client with a subnet of 10.10.23.x. Any others that start with 192.168.x.x are a no go. What am I missing here?

MacBook Pro 16" w/ Catalina, connected via WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need static route(s) to the VPN subnets with a lower metric than the VPN interface. Ie;
`route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0  192.168.4.2 METRIC 3 IF 11`

Where 192.168.4.2 is your physical eth ip, metric is a number lower than your VPN interfaces an IF is the physical eth ID (in windows).